# Django - ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable when returning Object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm having problems to return my object after I add some items into my "countries" ManytomanyField. I can see my data being saved

```
class CompanyProfileManager(models.Manager):
    @transaction.atomic
    def register_company(self, name, description, tag_name, email, is_private, uses_credits, pays_subscription, pool,
                     facebook, twitter, web, country, videocall_doctor_to_patient, micro_type, can_move, fixed_percentage, fixed_price, fixed_tariff, instagram, subdomain, banner_description, banner_title, countries,  **kwargs):
        tag = Tag(name=tag_name, description=tag_name, is_active=True)
        tag.save()

        company = self.create_instance(name, description, email, is_private, uses_credits, pays_subscription, pool,
                                   facebook, twitter, web, country, videocall_doctor_to_patient, micro_type, can_move, fixed_percentage, fixed_price, fixed_tariff, instagram, subdomain, banner_description, banner_title)

        company.tag = tag
        company.save()

        for item in countries:
            company.countries.add(item)

        return company #Using Debug Mode, My project breaks right here
```

I'm really lost, the only thing I've seen so far related to my problem is using .all() to get as a queryset

Answer (score 13):

ManyToMany attributes (in your case `countries`) are `Manager`, more exactly `ManyRelatedManager` and not `QuerySet`. A bit like `objects` in `QuerySet.objects` so you need to use `.all()` if you want to iterate through all your countries:

```
for item in countries.all():
    company.countries.add(item)
```

You can use other fancy methods as well like `.filters()`, `.select_related()`, etc...

**EDIT**

Since the variable `countries` is not a queryset but a list, I suspect that the error is not generated byt this chunk of code, probably just after when you try to iterate through `company.countries` instead of `company.countries.all()`

Comment: I get  - 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: Edited the answer